# For a sampling rate of 8 kHz how many instruction cycles can be inside the real-time execution loop if fosc = 8MHz?

Tags: clock, pic

I have a pic 16f886 and I want to know if you could explain how you get the answer of 250 instruction cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instruction on a PIC 16F886 requires four clock cycles to execute.

So if you're sampling at a rate of 8Khz, you can have 1000 clock transitions between each sample, and 1000 / 4 = 250 instructions that can be executed between each sample.

Comment: One last question, (sorry for the newbishnes), just out of curiosity if i was to change that sampling rate to lets say 4khz, would the clock transition remain at 1000 or decrease to 500

Comment: It would increase to 2000.